# Simple Fast read-process

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I want to decompress data from a file on a very slow device (read speed=1Mo/s). The decompression algorithm can at least perform three times this speed.
What is the fastest way to parallelize those tasks in C/C++ so that reading process cannot be slow down by decompression and so use maximum bandwidth.

I already tried two threads with regular pipes. But I don't know if it is the best solution. At least it is not a zero-copy algo.
My current algo is wrong because I cannot success to perform blocking IO on pipes. (tried fcntl or fread/fdopen)

My unparallelized program is very simple. Somethings like

```
while(remainingToRead > 0){
    int nb = fread(buffer, 1, bufferSize);
    decompress(buffer, nb, bufferOut);
    nb -= remainingToRead
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question.  If the program is IO bound, multi-threading won't make it any faster.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was my first reaction, but actually the question makes somewhat sense. That is after one chunk has been read, the decompression could take place while the next chunk is being read, thus the decompression will take no time at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver as I understand the idea is to perform reading while decompressing

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah yes.  That way you only have time of a single decompress, plus the file read time.

Comment: @NathanOliver understood my question. The idea is read process do not wait data to be decompressed and can read at "max" speed .

Answer (score 3):

One solution here is to use separate threads to read and decompress and to use two buffers so that these operations can be overlapped.

Pseudo code:

Read thread:

```
while (not finished)
{
    while (no buffers free)
        wait on condition variable
    fill next buffer
    mark buffer in use
    set condition variable for decompression thread
}
```

Decompression thread:

```
while (not finished)
{
    while (no buffers full)
        wait on condition variable
    decompress next buffer
    mark buffer free
    set condition variable for read thread
}
```

Note that getting this to work involves getting quite a bit of detail right - multi-threaded programming is always tricky.

Comment: Assuming the decompressed data must be stored somewhere, probably on the same slow device, then the largest buffer possible should be used. For example for a slow disk drive this optimizes (slow) head movement.

Comment: What is your advice for thread synchronization in this case ? Mutexes ?

Comment: @SVA522 on what platform will your program run?

Comment: It's an old MIPS embed linux. Data are read on µSD and bus speed is slow.

Comment: Do you have std::condition_variable and std::atomic?

Comment: Yes I have std::condition_variable and std::atomic. Thank for your reply.